# How to get the parent folder of a folder

Tags: java

Let's say we have:

```
String path = "D:\aaa\bbb\ccc"
```

I wonder if there is a function to modify quickly `path` to:

`D:\aaa\bbb\` or `D:\aaa\`

I tried to use [Paths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html) with no luck:

```
path = "D:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc";
pathNew = java.nio.file.Paths.get(path).subpath(0,2).toString();
println "${pathNew}"
```

Gives the next console result:

```
aaa\bbb
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
String path = "D:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc";
File parent = new File(path).getParentFile();
System.out.println(parent);

String parentStr = new File(path).getParent();
System.out.println(parentStr);
```

Prints:

```
D:\aaa\bbb
D:\aaa\bbb
```

Comment: Presumably he wants the string, so `getParent()` might be preferable. As in, `String parent = new File(path).getParent()`.

Comment: And `File parent = new File(path).getParentFile().getParentFile();` would result in: `D:\aaa`. Perfect! Why is better `getParent()`  @arshajii?

Comment: @chelder `getParent()` returns a string while `getParentFile()` returns a `File`. But if you need to chain the calls like that then use `getParentFile()`.

Comment: Nice. And `String parentStr = new File(path).getParentFile().getParent();` would result in: `D:\aaa` :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("D:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc");
Path p2 = p1.getParent();
....
```

Comment: I think you meant to escape out your \ with \\

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  Path path = Paths.get("your path");
  Path parentPath = path.getParent();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
File path = new File("D:\aaa\bbb\ccc");
path.getParentFile();  // Returns "D:\aaa\bbb\"
path.getParentFile().getParentFile();  // Returns D:\aaa\"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File parent = new File("D:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc").getParent();
System.out.println(parent);
```